# SetPriorityClass equivalent on Linux

Tags: linux, unix, process

I have a daemon-like application that does some disk-intensive processing at initialization. To avoid slowing down other tasks I do something like this on Windows:

```
SetPriorityClass(GetCurrentProcess(), PROCESS_MODE_BACKGROUND_BEGIN);

// initialization tasks

SetPriorityClass(GetCurrentProcess(), PROCESS_MODE_BACKGROUND_END);

// daemon is ready and running at normal priority
```

AFAIK, on Unices I can call nice or setpriority and lower the process priority but I can't raise it back to what it was at process creation (i.e. there's no equivalent to the second SetPriorityClass invocation) unless I have superuser privileges. Is there by any chance another way of doing it that I'm missing? (I know I can create an initialization thread that runs at low priority and wait for it to complete on the main thread, but I'd rather prefer avoiding it)

edit: Bonus points for the equivalent `SetThreadPriority(GetCurrentThread(), THREAD_MODE_BACKGROUND_BEGIN);` and `SetThreadPriority(GetCurrentThread(), THREAD_MODE_BACKGROUND_END);`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You've said that your processing is disk intensive, so solutions using `nice` won't work.  `nice` handles the priority of CPU access, not I/O access. `PROCESS_MODE_BACKGROUND_BEGIN` lowers I/O priority as well as CPU priority, and requires kernel features that don't exist in XP and older.

Controlling I/O priority is not portable across Unices, but there is a solution on modern Linux kernels. You'll need `CAP_SYS_ADMIN` to lower I/O priority to `IO_PRIO_CLASS_IDLE`, but it is possible to lower and raise priority within the best effort class without this.

The key function call is [`ioprio_set`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/ioprio_set), which you'll have to call via a `syscall` wrapper:

```
static int ioprio_set(int which, int who, int ioprio)
{
    return syscall(SYS_ioprio_set, which, who, ioprio);
}
```

For full example source, [see here](http://www.koders.com/c/fidB4E3C4484A9EFCA9E11BC62341D62F532C5FEC52.aspx?s=crc).

Depending on permissions, your entry to background mode is either `IOPRIO_PRIO_VALUE(IO_PRIO_CLASS_IDLE,0)` or `IOPRIO_PRIO_VALUE(IO_PRIO_CLASS_BE,7)`. The sequence should then be:

```
#define IOPRIO_PRIO_VALUE(class, data)  (((class) << IOPRIO_CLASS_SHIFT) | data)

ioprio_set(IOPRIO_WHO_PROCESS, 0, IOPRIO_PRIO_VALUE(IO_PRIO_CLASS_BE,7));
// Do work
ioprio_set(IOPRIO_WHO_PROCESS, 0, IOPRIO_PRIO_VALUE(IO_PRIO_CLASS_BE,4));
```

Note that you many not have permission to return to your original io priority, so you'll need to return to another best effort value.

Answer (score 3):

Actually, if you have a reasonably recent **Linux** kernel there might be a solution. Here's what TLPI says:

> In Linux kernels before 2.6.12, an
>   unprivileged process may use
>   setpriority() only to (irreversibly)
>   lower its own or another process’s
>   nice value.
>
> Since kernel 2.6.12, Linux provides
>   the RLIMIT_NICE resource limit, which
>   permits unprivileged processes to
>   increase nice values. An unprivileged
>   process can raise its own nice value
>   to the maximum specified by the
>   formula 20 – rlim_cur, where rlim_cur
>   is the current RLIMIT_NICE soft
>   resource limit.

So basically you have to:

1. Use **[`ulimit -e`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/bash)** to set RLIMIT_NICE
2. Use **[`setpriority`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/setpriority)** as usual

Here is an example

**Edit `/etc/security/limits.conf`**. Add

```
cnicutar    -    nice    -10
```

**Verify using ulimit**

```
cnicutar@aiur:~$ ulimit -e
30
```

We like that limit so we don't change it.

**nice ls**

```
cnicutar@aiur:~$ nice -n -10 ls tmp
cnicutar@aiur:~$ 

cnicutar@aiur:~$ nice -n -11 ls tmp
nice: cannot set niceness: Permission denied
```

**`setpriority` example**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/resource.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main()
{
        int rc;

        printf("We are being nice!\n");
        /* set our nice to 10 */
        rc = setpriority(PRIO_PROCESS, 0, 10);
        if (0 != rc) {
                perror("setpriority");
        }

        sleep(1);

        printf("Stop being nice\n");
        /* set our nice to -10 */
        rc = setpriority(PRIO_PROCESS, 0, -10);
        if (0 != rc) {
                perror("setpriority");
        }

        return 0;
}
```

**Test program**

```
cnicutar@aiur:~$ ./nnice 
We are being nice!
Stop being nice
cnicutar@aiur:~$
```

The only drawback to this is that it's not portable to other Unixes (or is it *Unices* ?).

Answer (score 0):

To workaroud lowering priority and then bringing it back you can:

1. fork()
2. CHILD: lower its priority
3. PARENT: wait for the child (keeping original parent's priority)
4. CHILD: do the job (in lower priority)
5. PARENT: continue with original priority after child is finished.

This should be UNIX-portable solution.

Comment: From the question: "(I know I can create an initialization thread that runs at low priority and wait for it to complete on the main thread, but I'd rather prefer avoiding it)"